# cannot access and run a script in docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I'm fuzzing php inside docker container. Before fuzzing process start, it download and build php from source, then run fuzzing job. I'm using `-d` to run container in background.

`sudo docker run --name=fuzzphp -d -v ~/crashfile:/fuzzer/script/fuzzing/ --privileged --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE fuzzphp /bin/bash -c "./tool/autophp.sh"`

Here is the `autophp.sh` script doing build and run php.

```
./script/build/buildphp.sh
./script/fuzzing/runphp.sh
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

#install required package

RUN mkdir -p /fuzzer

WORKDIR /fuzzer
COPY . /fuzzer

ENV PATH "/fuzzer/clang+llvm/bin:$PATH"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH "/fuzzer/clang+llvm/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

RUN ["chmod" "777" "-R" "script/"]
RUN tool/install_fuzzer.sh
```

The problem is after I run `autophp.sh` by checking `sudo docker logs fuzzphp` only build script success, and `runphp.sh` return an error

```
chmod: cannot access '/script/fuzzing/buildphp.sh': No such file or directory
./tool/autophp.sh: line 5: ./script/fuzzing/runphp.sh: No such file or directory
```

I can confirm `/script/fuzzing/runphp.sh` file is exist on host but I don't have idea only `buildphp` is executed, but not `runphp`. What's wrong here?

Comment: your COPY'ing the files but then mounting over the top `-v ~/crashfile:/fuzzer/script/fuzzing/` which unless that folder (~/crashfile) contains all the files which you copied like buildphp.sh they wont be found.. also what's odd is `chmod: cannot access '/script/fuzzing/buildphp.sh'` it should be /fuzzer/script/fuzzing/buildphp.sh.. you need to sanity check all the paths

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks for pointing out ```-v ~/crashfile:/fuzzer/script/fuzzing/```, I move the crash directory to other folder. It now works as intended